# How to make a dialog live as long as my activity lives (if user doesn't dismiss it)?

Tags: android, dialog

I am using `AlertDialog.Builder` to build and then show a dialog. When shown, I expect that dialog to stay up as long as the activity runs, so long as the user does not dismiss it.

The problem is that in my Galaxy S3, it works great, but in an HTC Wildfire or Desire, it doesn't work as expected. If i lock and unlock the screen, my dialog disappears.

How can I make it work on all devices?

Comment: unfortunately you are somewhat at the mercy of the system. I think your best bet is to save the state of your dialog in onPause() i.e. showing or not showing, and then in onResume() lookup that saved state and use it to determine if you should re-show the dialog. That may have unintended effects on the devices that do already work correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `DialogFragment` or building the `AlertDialog` in `onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args)` and showing it using `showDialog(int id)`. Many HTC devices aggressively reclaim memory, leaving your app in a state that is similar to a configuration change. Following these constraints should solve the issue.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html